# Switching values to labels in a new column

Tags: r, label

I got a column of labelled values. Let's call it country.
When I run:

```
attr(dat[["Country"]], "labels")
```

I get the next table:

```
USA      Germany       France           UK        Spain        India Saudi Arabia 
  1            2            3            4            5            6            7
```

Now I got a new column of int values that are not labelled. Let's call it newCountry. I would like to change those int values to the label of the original Country column. In other words, I would like to go from this in an efficient way...

3
2
2
1
5
4

to this...

France
Germany
Germany
USA
Spain
UK

Comment: Just extract `attr(dat[["Country"]], "labels")[i]` where `i <- c(3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 4)`.

Comment: I have tried that but it just returns the number again not the actual label.

Comment: OK, it seems that the labels have names. Assign the output of `attr(etc)` to, say, `labs`. What does `names(labs)` return? If it returns the countries names then extract from those, `names(labs)[i]`.

Comment: Cool! It does return the countries names. However this approach may only work if the label number (1,2,3,4,5...) starts in 1 and is sequential.

Comment: No, it will work irrespective of the labels themselves, it's the *names* of a vector (which happens to be the labels) that is being subset by `i`. Maybe it's better if I explain in an answer?

Comment: The i in attr(dat[["Country"]], "labels")[i] will return the label thtat is in position i not in the one that has the value i. Therefore, it works the same way with names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the data frame has a column, `Country`, with the attribute `"labels"` set. In its turn, this attribute, which is just a vector, has the attribute `"names"` set. So the steps to get the `"names"` of the `"labels"` are:

1. Get the `"labels"` of column `Country`;
2. Get the `"names"` of the vector of labels;
3. Extract the names corresponding to a vector of indices, the vector `i`.

First read in the posted data.

```
nms <- scan(text = "USA Germany France UK Spain India 'Saudi Arabia'",
            what = character())
i <- scan(text = "3 2 2 1 5 4")
```

Now create a data set example.

```
labs <- setNames(1:7, nms)
dat <- data.frame(Country = sample(letters, 7))
attr(dat[["Country"]], "labels") <- labs
```

And extract what the question asks for, following the steps above.

```
labsCountry <- attr(dat[["Country"]], "labels")
names(labsCountry)[i]
#[1] "France"  "Germany" "Germany" "USA"     "Spain"   "UK"
```

Or a one-liner:

```
names(attr(dat[["Country"]], "labels"))[i]
#[1] "France"  "Germany" "Germany" "USA"     "Spain"   "UK"
```

To see that this does not depend on the values of the labels, create a second example.

```
labs2 <- setNames(101:107, nms)
attr(dat[["Country"]], "labels") <- labs2
```

And though the `"labels"` are different,  the same instructions work:

```
attr(dat[["Country"]], "labels")
#         USA      Germany       France           UK        Spain        India Saudi Arabia 
#         101          102          103          104          105          106          107

labsCountry <- attr(dat[["Country"]], "labels")
names(labsCountry)[i]
```

Comment: Well, I am facing an issue with this solution. When I get a labelled value of 0, this doesn't work as the match is done assuming by index assuming that labelled values start in 0. Imagine USA is 0 instead of 1. Do you have any idea how we could fix this?

Comment: @SarahíAguilar In R vectors are 1-based. If the label of USA is `"0"`, it will still be the 1st element of the labels vector and the code should work. Can you edit the question with an example where it fails?

Comment: Exactly. But I have managed to fix this already. What I did was simply a table with values and their labels and then matched that with the array values. Thanks, though!